# SP13: Showing Image in Custom List

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list, calculated-column, image

The first part is working not the second.

Intent: To have users select add attachment button on a custom list new form. Then select browse button that allows to browse out to select image on computer.  Once save the image appears in the custom list.

Problem: The browse button allows the user to browse out to add the photo, but the photo doesn't appear in the column just the destination URL.

Steps to resolve:

1. Placed the browse button code to the new form
2. Created a image column type

Is there way by either using a calculated field or scripting that will convert the destination url into a image into another column?  Thanks for your help.

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>Attach Files</nobr>
</h3>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="attachmentsOnClient" style="width: 434px">
<span dir=”ltr”>
<input type=”file” name=”fileupload0″ id=”onetidIOFile” size=”56″ title=”Name”>              </input>
</span>
</td>
<td width="100px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
<input name="Button1" type=”button” value="Attach" onclick='OkAttach()'       style="width: 6em;
 height: 1.7em" />
<span id="idSpace"></span>
</td>
</tr>
</style>
```

Comment: if this is your HTML.. you can not define HTML **inside** a ``style`` tag. Calculated Column with HTML won't help because they only work on Views, not on Forms

Comment: Good points.  Thank you @DannyEngelman I will take another look.

Comment: Sadly, I can't elaborate more at the moment, but I think that you may find what you need if you look into client side rendering/ jslink. If all you need is to render the column value as an img tag, it should be doable.